# How to control tensorflow's VLOG?

Tags: tensorflow

I used VLOG to print log. VLOG is defined as below：

```
#define VLOG_IS_ON(lvl) \
   ((lvl) <= ::tensorflow::internal::LogMessage::MinVLogLevel())
#endif

#define VLOG(lvl)      \
  if (TF_PREDICT_FALSE(VLOG_IS_ON(lvl))) \
  ::tensorflow::internal::LogMessage(__FILE__, __LINE__, tensorflow::INFO)

const int INFO = 0;            // base_logging::INFO;
const int WARNING = 1;         // base_logging::WARNING;
const int ERROR = 2;           // base_logging::ERROR;
const int FATAL = 3;           // base_logging::FATAL;
const int NUM_SEVERITIES = 4;  // base_logging::NUM_SEVERITIES;
```

If I configure the min log level with warning, I use `export TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL=1`. What I want is for the log only to print WARNINGs including ERROR, FATAL， but in fact, it is only displaying WARNING and INFO logs which are called by:

```
VLOG(INFO) and VLOG(WARN)
```

Is this result reasonable? How can I adjust the log levels accordingly?

Comment: export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0   
export TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL=3   , if you want more message, just increase the TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL value

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You control the log level via `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` (not `TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL`), which you want to set to 1 in your case.

`TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL` brings in extra debugging information and actually works the other way round: its default value is 0 and as it increases, more debugging messages are logged in.

So the `VLOG` level is not your usual `INFO`, `WARNING`, etc. `LOG` level, but something different and ranked inversely. If you peek into the code, you see that `LOG` is used with log labels (`LOG(INFO) << message`) but `VLOG` is used with plain numbers (`VLOG(2) << message`).

`VLOG` messages are actually always logged at the `INFO` log level. It means that in any case, you need a `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` of 0 to see any `VLOG` message.

Comment: As of TF 2.5.0rc0, "The `TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL` environment variable has been renamed to to `TF_CPP_MAX_VLOG_LEVEL` which correctly describes its effect."